# Constrain Type to be a keyof T and to be a specific type

Tags: typescript, ramda.js, typescript-generics

Consider

```
export function sortByProp<T extends Record<string, any>>(propName: keyof T) {
  return sort((a, b) => a[propName].localeCompare(b[propName]))
```

I wish to ensure that `propName` is also a typeof `string`

results in

> Property 'localeCompare' does not exist on type 'unknown'.ts(2339)

How is this achieved?

Ok this gets me a bit further:

```
export const sortByProp = <T extends Record<string, any>>(propName: keyof T) => {
  return sort<T>((a, b) => a[propName].localeCompare(b[propName]))
}
```

Consumed with

```
 sortByProp('hostname')(data.devices.devicePageEntries).map(x => ({
          key: x.id,
          value: x.hostname,
        }))
```

But then i get

> Property 'id' does not exist on type '{ hostname: any; }

Casting in my caller method seems to solve things,

```
 (sortByProp('hostname')(
          data.devices.devicePageEntries,
        ) as DevicePageEntry[])
```

I'm on Ramda 0.25.0

Comment: Can you share `sort` function implementation? There is no relation between predicate and your `sortByProp` currently. To know how to fix it I need to see the `sort` or at least type definition

Comment: updated tags to include ramda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```
import { sort } from "ramda";

export function sortByProp<K extends string>(propName: K) {
  return <T extends Record<K, string>>(arr: T[]) =>
    sort((a: T, b: T) => a[propName].localeCompare(b[propName]))(arr);
}

const result = sortByProp("hostname")([
  { hostname: "foo", id: 1 },
  { hostname: "bar", id: 2 }
]); 
// [{"hostname":"bar","id":2},{"hostname":"foo","id":1}]

const mappedResult = result.map(x => ({
  key: x.id, // works
  value: x.hostname
})); 
// [{"key":2,"value":"bar"},{"key":1,"value":"foo"}]
```

[Code sample on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-rxq3m2)

I declared type parameter `T` with constraint `extends Record<K, string>` to ensure, that `localeCompare` is always invoked on a `string` property value.

In addition, the compiler cannot infer a property value type for [generic type parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) `T` by solely looking at function parameter `propName: keyof T`, so it takes `any` from `T`'s [base constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) `Record<string, any>`. Further reason is: [Inference candidates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html) for  `T` are collected by looking at the function declaration signature (parameters and return type), not at the function body/implementation. TypeScript also only consults the directly with `T` annotated function, not inner function declarations, for possible candidates.

By declaring `T` as part of the inner function, TypeScript can make use of function parameter `arr: T[]` to infer `T`.

#### Alternative `sort` with pure JS

```
function sort<T>(cb: (t1: T, t2: T) => number) {
  return (arr: T[]) => [...arr].sort(cb);
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZzgJygIQJ4AU1wAOAPANKICmAHlBWACbIpRoxgDmAfABSEGEA5AIYBbCgC5EpAJSIA3gChEiNBSgg0SYgBVKNOo0QAlChHT0yAGmasOnHkLRpJ2gNoBdWQF5OS5SnQobm4hF2sAIxdvTkQhVz4iYTF3ADoAGzgIITSKAGE4EUJHCm5w%20P4kik9pEKdpAG4FAF8FBVBIWAQAjB0eCEjEbigARjDEKAAmKMQfRDAQEXCKNFlFZVV1TUHHZ0Q3TxmY1xSTndTUDG5%20hubWszBkKBUKZBA0p69urDx%20bgAiAAWcEeYFEFD%20NVcfjkiCBILBkj%20wDgcD%201hg9Ekw0QTUs0NhwKgoLEiPCjjRiAxkgmOIUnnqiDuCEeiBEQkIhAo9BMr3eM2evKgKTZhG4VEOgzWiAA1hRsJIqCkMdYAPQqxAAd3Q0qYYDgGr8ADdsiAJIhFXCiWDmtIGoyFPdUDl0nB2NxVILZGrEK45IDCcTweI-mS0Gi-hi-uIJri-ZbA1GkSjw5HxMMmu4Hcy4M6Mm6RZzuS83lAverfX9ZdgoxNLH9jWlTYnQ39Y5W5VHhnWG03g8jURmgA)